# Please tell me how to resolve a type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a program that turns two data into a new one.
Each of the data comes from an API, so the undefined case must be considered.

but,

```
item.id === message.sender.userId
```

A type error occurs in userId in the section.

I want to resolve this type error.
I want to solve it by a means that does not change the type or data.
Is this possible?

```js
  const newMessages = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (messages === undefined || userItems === undefined) return [];
    return messages.map(message => {
      if (message.sender.type === "user" && message.sender.userId) {
        const user = userItems.find(item => item.id === message.sender.userId);
        if (user) message.sender = { ...message.sender, icon: user.image };
      }
      return message;
    });
  }, [messages, userItems]);
```

Here are the two data I'm getting, and the type of one:

```js
type IMessage = {
  sender:
    | {
        type: "user";
        userId: number;
      }
    | {
        type: "admin";
        adminId: number;
      };
  body:
    | {
        type: "text";
        text: "text";
      }
    | {
        type: "image";
        text: string;
        image: string;
      };
};


const messages: IMessage[] =
[
    {
        "sender": {
            "type": "admin",
            "adminId": 789
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "image",
            "text": "abcde",
            "image": "https://imageUrl"
        },
    },
    {
        "sender": {
            "type": "user",
            "userId": 10
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Hello!"
        },
    },
    {
        "sender": {
            "type": "user",
            "userId": 13
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "image",
            "text": "Hello my friend!",
            "image": "https://imageUrl"
        },
    },
]

const userItems =
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "kenny",
        "image": "https://imageUrl",
        "age": 23,
        "gender": "M",
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Jon",
        "image": "https://imageUrl",
        "age": 32,
        "gender": "M",
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const user = userItems.find(item => item.id === message.sender.userId);
```

You and i know that this function is going to be called right away, but typescript does not. In general, a callback function could be called at any time, synchronously or asynchronously, and nothing in the type information specifies that. As a result, typescript cannot guarantee that message.sender will still be a user when the callback gets called.

To fix this, assign the value to a const, so typescript can know for sure it won't change.

```
if (message.sender.type === "user" && message.sender.userId) {
  const userId = message.sender.userId
  const user = userItems.find(item => item.id === userId);
// ...
```

---

P.S:

```
body:
    | {
        type: "text";
        text: "text";
      }
```

You probably meant to do `text: string`